# About the arguments of the binary function in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, constants

I'm confused when the arguments of the binary function should be `const T &` or `T &`.

Could anyone tell me why `sort(vec2.begin(), vec2.end(),cmp1());//error, why?` is wrong, while `sort(vec1.begin(), vec1.end(),cmp2());//correct` is right?

They all have `const T &` arguments.

Thanks!

```
struct Node{
    Node(char ch, int num):ch_(ch), num_(num){ pnext_ = nullptr, pprev_ = nullptr; }
    char ch_;
    int num_;
    Node *pnext_;
    Node *pprev_;
    // bool operator < (const Node &no) const { return num_ > no.num_; }//最小值优先
    // bool operator > (const Node &no) const { return num_ < no.num_; }//最大值优先
};
struct cmp0{
    bool operator () (Node * &p1, Node * &p2) const
    {
        return p1->num_ > p2->num_;
    }
};
struct cmp1{
    bool operator ()(const Node * &p1, const Node * &p2) const
    {
        return p1->num_ > p2->num_;
    }
};
struct cmp2{
    bool operator ()(const Node &p1, const Node &p2) const
    {
        return p1.num_ > p2.num_;
    }
};
struct cmp3{
    bool operator ()(Node &p1, Node &p2) const
    {
        return p1.num_ > p2.num_;
    }
};
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    vector<Node> vec1;
    vector<Node*> vec2;
    sort(vec1.begin(), vec1.end(),cmp2());//correct
    sort(vec1.begin(), vec1.end(), cmp3());//correct
    sort(vec2.begin(), vec2.end(), cmp0());//correct
    sort(vec2.begin(), vec2.end(),cmp1());//error, why?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> They all have const T & arguments.

It might be confusing, but for `cmp1` the parameter type (i.e. `const Node *&`) is not `const T&` (with `T==Node*`), which should be `Node* const&`. Note the difference between const pointer (`Node* const`) and pointer to const (`const Node*`).

> `sort(vec2.begin(), vec2.end(),cmp1());//error, why?`

The element type is `Node*`, which couldn't be bound to `const Node* &`. Because `Node*` and `const Node*` is not the same type, it need to be converted to `const Node*`, which will be a temporary and can't be bound to lvalue reference to non-const.

Answer (score 1):

`const Node*` is not a `const` pointer. It is a pointer to a `const Node`. This is a source of confusion for many.

You can use:

```
struct cmp1{
    bool operator ()(Node* p1, Node* p2) const
    {
        return p1->num_ > p2->num_;
    }
};
```

or

```
struct cmp1{
    bool operator ()(Node* const & p1, Node* const & p2) const
    {
        return p1->num_ > p2->num_;
    }
};
```

Instead of the thinking that the argument type has to be `const T &`, think that it has to be `T const &`. Then, it will make sense why `const Node* &` is not the right type and why `Node* const &` is the right type.